# Why is data table in VB 2010 and SQL Server starting with a negative primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I defined a database using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, and connected to it using Visual Basic 2010 Express. For some reason though, when I use the database in the program, it wants to start off using a negative primary key.

Is there any way to make the primary key only a positive number?

Comment: Post the DDL of your table and the code used to write to it, that would be a big help in answering your question.

Comment: Why does it matter? If you're using an identity column as your primary key, all you should care about is that the values are automatically unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @RNarry Young response. You can check the schema if your table

Suppose you have the following table

```
create table #t
(
    ID int Identity(-1, 1),
    s varchar(100)
)
```

Now you make two inserts

```
Insert into #t(s) values('ed')
Insert into #t(s) values('ed')
```

Check the output

```
select * from #t
```

It shows like below. If you see the screen shot. **The first row shows -1 in the primary key value**. Due to the reason that the Identity Seed is -1 mentioned in the schema.

[image]

You can get rid of this issue. We should use the schema like below.

```
 create table #t
    (
        ID int Identity(1, 1),
        s varchar(100)
    )
```

Following is the other way to generate

```
Set Identity_Insert #t On
Insert into #t(ID, s) values(-1, 'ed')
Set Identity_Insert #t OFF

Set Identity_Insert #t On 
Insert into #t(ID, s) values(-2, 'ed') 
Set Identity_Insert #t OFF
```

Comment: I created the table in Visual Basic (connected to SQL Server Express). I checked the identity specification, and it's set to a seed of 1, and an increment of 1. Perhaps I shouldn't have set the datatype to bigint?

Comment: I think I figured it out. In the XSD file, in the properties for the primary key, it was set to a seed of -1. Go figure that the XSD file would ignore the MDF settings. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Off hand I can only think of two things that would cause this:

1. When creating the table you (or some software/code you are using) is setting the Identity seed to a negative number.
2. Or, you (or some software/code you are using) are using Identity_Insert and just forcing a negative number in.

Answer (score 0):

The identity seed for the table will be visible within SSMS.

But.... it doesn't matter in the slightest that it's producing negative numbers. There's only really two practical concerns about your identiity value:

1. Unique values
2. Sufficient space to cover the expected range of values (so, a tinyint key wouldn't be great for tracking the entire world population...)

Once they're sorted, the actual values shouldn't be of any concern at all. They're internal to the database.